# Remove border from table in another table

Tags: html, css

For some reason I need a table in a table. The parent table has a border at each but the last `<tr>`. The child table should have no borders at all. Yet, I can't get them removed with CSS. Tried several solutions I could find on SO but none worked for me. Strangely enough the rest of the CSS comes across, only borders are persistant...

```css
.table_wrapzm {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.table_wrapzm tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.table_wrapzm .h3 {
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.table_wrapzm .bron {
  font-size: small;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ddd;
}

.table_wrapzm a:link {
  color: #ddd;
}

.table_wrapzm a:visited {
  color: #ddd;
}

.table_wrapzm a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.table_wrapzm a:active {
  color: #ddd;
}

.table_wrapzm td {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.table_wrapzm tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.table_wrapzm .main {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}


/* tabel inside table */

.table_zm {
  border: none !important;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.table_zm .h3 {
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table_zm td {
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table_wrapzm">
  <tr>
    <td class="h3">Title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="main">
      <table class="table_zm">
        <tr>
          <td>Row 1 col 1</td>
          <td>Row 1 col 2</td>
          <td>row 1 col 3</td>
          <td>Row 1 col 4</td>
          <td>row 1 col 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row 2 col 1</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>row 2 col 3</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>row 2 col 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row 3 col 1</td>
          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Row 3 col 5</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> source</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Define border styles to table cells, not to table itself, as `.table_zm td { border: 0 none; }`.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing what exactly you are trying to remove https://codepen.io/pjabbott/pen/wdWMBB

Comment: @skobaljic that works! I think I tried it but it was still in cach so after a refresh your solution works!

Comment: There are some [table elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) you may use (at least wrap columns with `<tbody>`, cause browser will wrap it anyway). Glad I helped, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
.table_zm td { border: 0 none; }
```

As suggested by @skobaljic did the job. Many thanks!